# Arduino static progmem cannot be accessed via variables

Tags: c++, arduino, e-ink

I cannot reference a 3d array of bytes stored in memory via variables

```
  letter[18][0]=letters[L][18][0];
  letter[18][1]=letters[L][18][1];
  letter[19][0]=letters[L][19][0];
  letter[19][1]=letters[L][19][1];
  for(int i = 20;i<32;i++){
    static int test = i;
    letter[i][0]=letters[L][i][0];
    letter[i][1]=letters[L][i][1];
  }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkvxw.jpg

The section in the for loop produces garbage, in this case all zeros but it can be other nonsense if other characters are selected

```
const uint8_t letters[96][32][2] PROGMEM = {{{255,255}//' '
,{255,255}
,{255,255}
,{255,255}
,{255,255}
,{255,255}
,{255,255}
,{255,255}
,{255,255}
,{255,255}
...
```

this is how i declared the array i am using as a lookup table

Comment: Try reading the datasheet and application notes for your part.  Crack the documentation to learn how to use PROGMEM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access variables marked as `PROGMEM` like standard variable. You have to use special functions to read values from them.

[PROGMEM - Arduino Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/)

It will be like this:

```
  letter[18][0]=pgm_read_byte_near(&letters[L][18][0]);
  letter[18][1]=pgm_read_byte_near(&letters[L][18][1]);
  letter[19][0]=pgm_read_byte_near(&letters[L][19][0]);
  letter[19][1]=pgm_read_byte_near(&letters[L][19][1]);
  for(int i = 20;i<32;i++){
    static int test = i;
    letter[i][0]=pgm_read_byte_near(&letters[L][i][0]);
    letter[i][1]=pgm_read_byte_near(&letters[L][i][1]);
  }
```